# how to convert or import crystal report to activereports 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, activereports

I have visual studio 2010 ultimate, crystal reports, and Active Reports 7, I need to convert my crystal reports to Active Reports 7. In VS 2010 crystal report I clicked on tools Convert to Active Reports 7 and get the following message:`ActiveReports Developer Upgrade tool "there is no content to upgrade in (project name) project.`

Should create ActiveReport first? How do you convert the crystal reports to ActiveReports?

Answer (score 1):

The "Convert to ActiveReports 7" command is used to convert a project from ActiveReports 6 or earlier up to ActiveReports 7.

What you want to do is run the "ActiveReports Developer Import" application from the Start Menu.  Unfortunately, I'm running Windows 8 so I can't tell you where exactly its located, but its somewhere under ComponentOne\ActiveReports Developer.

Here is our documentation on using the [Import Wizard](http://downloads.gcpowertools.com/arhelp/?Converting%20with%20Import%20Wizard.html).